# DocumentDB: SQL to select match on optional element

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Say I have these 3 documents in a DocumentDB collection:

```
[
    {
        "name": "tiger",
        "keywords": [
            "animal",
            "cat",
            "stripes"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "cat"
    },
    {
        "keywords": [
            "panther",
            "black"
        ]
    }
]
```

How would I structure a single SQL query to return all documents where the 'name' matches "cat" OR a 'keyword' matches "cat" when 'keywords' and 'name' are optional elements in the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

SELECT *
FROM root r
WHERE r.name = 'cat' OR ARRAY_CONTAINS(r.keywords, 'cat')

Comment: Works great. Do you know how to modify the query so that ARRAY_CONTAINS matches partial strings in the same way as CONTAINS? At the moment ARRAY_CONTAINS must match the string exactly. For example the string "ca": SELECT * FROM root r WHERE CONTAINS(r.name,'ca') OR ARRAY_CONTAINS(r.keywords, 'ca')

Comment: ARRAY_CONTAINS performs a strict equality comparison of the search item against each item in the array. Mind you that the search item could be of any type.

An alternative approach here is to do 
    SELECT VALUE r 
    FROM root r 
    JOIN k IN r.keywords
    WHERE CONTAINS(r.name, 'ca') OR CONTAINS(k, 'ca') 

Please keep in mind that JOIN will flatten the keywords array and the result set is the cross product of the input documents with each item in the array.
For instance, this query will return the second document twice since r.name satisfies the condition for both array items.